# VBA GoalSeek for-loop for multiple column and multiple sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change it into for-loop in VBA?

```
Sub GoalSeekV1()
            
            Range("E34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$F$73")
            Range("F34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$G$73")
            Range("G34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$H$73")
            Range("H34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$I$73")
            Range("I34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$J$73")
            Range("J34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$K$73")
            Range("K34").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Inputs!$L$73")

End Sub
```

I had tried to use .cell(x, y) but failed, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that you can do this with a loop:

```vb
Sub GoalSeekV1()

    Dim rngStartGoal As Range
    Set rngStartGoal = Range("E34")
    
    Dim rngStartInput As Range
    Set rngStartInput = Range("Inputs!$F$73")
    
    Dim columnOffset As Integer
    For columnOffset = 0 To 6
        rngStartGoal.Offset(0, columnOffset).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=rngStartInput.Offset(0, columnOffset)
    Next

End Sub
```

I would recommend naming the start goal cell and start input cell, because you can then use those names in the code. So the code would be something like `Set rngStartGoal = Range("START_GOAL")` instead of `Set rngStartGoal = Range("E34")`. This has another advantage: if you move those cells, the code will still work.